# Language missing from node field arrays

Tags: 7, entities, nodes

For some fields, not all, the language index is missing from the field array. For example, here is the `body` field of the packaged `blog` content type (using `print_r`):

```
[body] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [value] => <p>Shirley Temple[...]
                [summary] => <p>Shirley Temple[...]
                [format] => html_raw
                [safe_value] => <p>Shirley Temple[...]
                [safe_summary] => <p>Shirley Temple[...]
            )
    )
```

Expected structure:

```
[body] => Array
        (
            [und] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [value] => <p>Shirley Temple[...]
                            [summary] => <p>Shirley Temple[...]
                            [format] => html_raw
                            [safe_value] => <p>Shirley Temple[...]
                            [safe_summary] => <p>Shirley Temple[...]
                        )
                )
        )
```

I have only ever seen this happen on two fields (the one above and another field from a different content type). Other fields on the `blog` content type are fine. It looks like it is only happening on my development environment, production seems to be fine. If I set `$reset` to `true` when calling [`node_load()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.module/function/node_load/7) then the structure is fine.

[`field_get_items()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.module/function/field_get_items/7) returns `false` and wrapping the node using the [Entity API](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.module/function/node_load/7)'s [`entity_metadata_wrapper()`](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!entity!entity.module/function/entity_metadata_wrapper/7) and calling `$wrapped_node->body->value()` I gives the following PHP error:

> EntityMetadataWrapperException: Missing data values. in EntityMetadataWrapper->value() (line 83 of /vagrant/web/sites/all/modules/entity/includes/entity.wrapper.inc).

Setup:

> Drupal 7.28
>   PHP 5.3.10
>   MySQL 5.5.34
>   Apache 2.2.22
>   memcached 1.4.13

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't run into this issue again. I think a Drupal update resolved the problem.